# How to get text between custom dynamic html tags without end tags

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

I have text separated by multiple custom tags with partially dynamic names and without closing tags.

What I need is to get all of the individual parts of the text **between** the custom tags, **not** including the tags.

For the last part of text, I can only get text **after** the tag, because it doesn't have a closing tag.

I've seen plenty of similar questions,but I didn't find them sufficient to solve my problem.

Example:

```
<*fixedTagName|Dynamic part of tag name> // * and | are included in fixed part of tag name
                                   //dynamic part can have spaces between words

  Random text I need to get of unknown length

  some paragraphs of text can start like this(look bellow)

  » name: value
  » name: value

<*fixedTagName|Dynamic part of tag>

  More random text I need to get

<*fixedTagName|Dynamic part of tag>

  Final part of random text I need to get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a text between regular expression matches you can use the `preg_split` function:

```
$result = preg_split('/<\*[^|]+\|[^>]+>/', $input);
```

In this regular expression:

- `<\*` matches `<*`;
- `[^|]+` matches any symbol except `|` 1..* times;
- `\|` matches `|`;
- `[^>]+` matches any symbol except `>` 1..* times;
- `>` matches `>`.

With this input:

```
$input = <<<EOL
<*fixedTagName|Dynamic part of tag name> // * and | are included in fixed part of tag name
                                   //dynamic part can have spaces between words

  Random text I need to get of unknown length

  some paragraphs of text can start like this(look bellow)

  » name: value
  » name: value

<*fixedTagName|Dynamic part of tag>

  More random text I need to get

<*fixedTagName|Dynamic part of tag>

  Final part of random text I need to get
EOL;
```

The `$result` will be an array of string something like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] =>  // * and | are included in fixed part of tag name
                                   //dynamic part can have spaces between words

  Random text I need to get of unknown length

  some paragraphs of text can start like this(look bellow)

  » name: value
  » name: value


    [2] => 

  More random text I need to get


    [3] => 

  Final part of random text I need to get
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This has to be the best answer I've recived so far on SO, it didn't just give the solution, but also the explanation with example. I gladly upvoted and accepted this answer. Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

I think this StackOverflow answer fully explain how you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/7578179

Comment: Listing the tools I can use !== fully explaining how to this. I knew before that I can use things like regex and/or parsers, but this problem is somewhat unique and very complex, probably out of my league at the moment, so I was hoping for something a bit more specific.